# How to suppress transcoding warnings during a proc import?

Tags: sas

I am trying to import a file that returns the following WARNING on import:

WARNING: Some character data was lost during transcoding in column: var16 at obs 234.

I have tried encoding as utf-8, utf-16, and utf-32 to have this warning disappear to no avail. Is there a way to only suppress this transcoding warning? The character that is causing this issue is:

Unicode Character “╕” (U+2555)

Comment: What encoding is your SAS session using? Check system option ENCODING.  Show the code you tried.

Comment: filename test "<filepath>/data.xlsx" encoding =  "utf-8";

proc import datafile = test
 out=output_data
 dbms=xlsx replace;
run;

Comment: ENCODING=LATIN1 is the encoding for the SAS session

Comment: You cannot store that character using LATIN1 encoding. That is single byte so only 256 possible characters. None of them is that one.

Comment: Does that mean I can't import that data at all into SAS?

Comment: You should be able to start SAS with ENCODING=UTF-8.   How depends on how you are access SAS.  Command line? Windows Icon/Start Menu?  SAS/Studio? Enterprise Guide?

Comment: I'm using SAS EG but don't have admin access.